# How to enlarge the width of the vertical scrollbar in qcombobox

Tags: c++, qt

I want to enlarge the width of the vertical scrollbar from a qcombobox in C++. I tried it in the following way:

```
comboBox->setStyleSheet( "QScrollBar:vertical { width: 30px; }");
```

but it shows no effect.

Can anyone give me a tip how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass your style and reimplement `QStyle::pixelMetric()` to return the width you want when the metric is `QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent` :

```
class Style : public QWindowsStyle
{
public:
  Style()
  {
  }
  int pixelMetric ( PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption * option = 0, const QWidget * widget = 0 ) const
  {
    if (metric == QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent)
      return 30;
    return QWindowsStyle::pixelMetric(metric, option, widget);
  }

};
```

And set the style of your combobox :

```
comboBox->setStyle(new Style());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.comboBox.view().verticalScrollBar().setStyleSheet("width: 30px;")
```

works on python. please make update on C++

Comment: The question is asking specifically about C++ and your answer is in Python? I'm not sure you understand how to answer this question.

Comment: Hi Joel, this question is by Qt layout ,as we all know, Qt have two version Qt C++ and Qt Python(pyside6 or PyQt6).  so the layout code  can reference as I motioned